# class datetime.time is not convertible to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python coming from R background,I have following time column in pandas

```
   time
   09:12:23
   09:34:33
   10:23:22
   11:23:33
```

I want to convert this into time object of pandas,I am doing following in python

```
     df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.time
```

Why its showing me following error.

```
   class datetime.time is not convertible to datetime
```

Comment: Waht kind of error?

Answer (score 5):

If possible same non datetime/time values add parameter `errors='coerce'`:

```
print (df)
       time
0     aaaaa
1  09:34:33
2  10:23:22
3  11:23:33

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], errors='coerce').dt.time
print (df)
       time
0       NaT
1  09:34:33
2  10:23:22
3  11:23:33
```

EDIT: For check this values:

```
print (df[pd.to_datetime(df['time'], errors='coerce').isnull()])
    time
0  sdass
```

EDIT1:

Here is possible convert to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) - advantage is using pandas [timedelta](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) functions, which not working with `time`s:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
      time
0      NaT
1 09:34:33
2 10:23:22
3 11:23:33
```

Comment: Can I know what kind of non date/time values it has? Because I have huge dataframe over a million observations.

Comment: @anmolmore - it means there is some non standard format of data, or maybe traling witespaces